# How to add all elements of vector (int16) in opencl on vector processor SIMD?

Tags: opencl, signal-processing, matrix-multiplication, simd, vdsp

While doing matrix multiplication on SIMD, I am facing problem in adding all elements of the vector.

```
float16 sum = row * column;
```

Now as sum is vector variable of 16 values. I want to add all the values for matrix multiplication.
Is there a built in function in opencl or using mac unit?

PS: the dot function only works with float4

Comment: Do you want to do a matrix multiplication of a 4x4 matrix with a 4-component vector? Or a 16x16 matrix multiplication with a 16-component vector?

Comment: Does every GPU thread have to perform the matrix multiplication on different data or do you want to parallelize the matrix multiplication itself?

Comment: i want to do 16x16 mat mul with 16 comp vec

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to perform a matrix-vector multiplicattion `y=M*x` with every GPU thread on different data, you could do the `float16` dot product manually:

```c
float sum = row.s0*column.s0+row.s1*column.s1+...+row.sf*column.sf;
```

However the better solution here is to ditch OpenCL vector data types entirely and go with `float` instead. Then the `y=M*x` is implemented like this:

```c
#define def_dim 16 // matrix dimension
float M[def_dim*def_dim]; // matrix
float x[def_dim]; // input vector

// fill M and x wih data

float y[def_dim]; // result vector
#pragma unroll // improve performance by loop unrolling
for(uint i=0; i<def_dim; i++) {
    y[i] = 0.0f;
    #pragma unroll // inprove performance by loop unrolling
    for(uint j=0; j<def_dim; j++) y[i] = fma(M[i*def_dim+j], x[j], y[i]); // multiply y=M*x
}
```

Comment: If row x column gets large do you need a bigger float to hold the sum?

Comment: @Holmz no, 32-bit float is fine here. Only for applications like matrix inversion on the CPU I would recommend doing summations in 64-bit double, but GPUs struggle with double.

Answer (score 0):

So to add the elements of vector, add all them individually.
As of now no standard function from opencl is available for this.

```
        // Adding all the elements of the vector
        desiredSum += sum.s0;
        desiredSum += sum.s1;
        desiredSum += sum.s2;
        desiredSum += sum.s3;
        desiredSum += sum.s4;
        desiredSum += sum.s5;
        desiredSum += sum.s6;
        desiredSum += sum.s7;
        desiredSum += sum.s8;
        desiredSum += sum.s9;
        desiredSum += sum.sa;
        desiredSum += sum.sb;
        desiredSum += sum.sc;
        desiredSum += sum.sd;
        desiredSum += sum.se;
        desiredSum += sum.sf;
```